# string value to JSON object in java but No value for

Tags: java, android, json

response

```
deneme2="{\"NUKE_USER_NO\":\"1494\",\"WEB_PIN\":\"metin\",\"CARI_NO\":\"2611\",\"FIRMA_ADI\":\"\",\"CARI_UNVANI\":\"LTDSTI\",\"MOD\":\"Müşteri\",\"RENK\":\"'#fbbb5e'\",\"EMAIL\":\"yok\",\"SAHIS_NO\":\"9\",\"ADISOYADI\":\"Metin\",\"YETKILER\":\"UrunListesi, KampanyaList, YeniUrunler, SepetListe, SiparisTakip, BekleyenSiparisler, TaksitBilgi, TaksitliOdeme, CariEkstre, HavaleEftBildir, BankaHesapNumaralari, PcShirbazi, IadeTalep, IadeSonuclari, GarantiSorgulama, ArizaTakip, UyelikBilgilerim, KullaniciList, SevkAdres, CariHareketler, BorcAlacakDurumu, AlisAnalizi, AlisCirolari, BABS, StandartFormlar, ArizaIadeProseduru, SevkiyatProseduru, Organizasyon, Iletisim, SiparisVerme, GuvenliOdeme3D, MailOrderOranlari, KargoTakip, FiyatMod, AnaSayfa, MusteriTemsilcisiniGorsun, Ihaleler, Puanlarim, UyeIsyeri, IadeDegerlendir, IadeSonucDepo\",\"CARI_TIP_NO\":\"6\",\"AKTIF_SEPET\":\"197\",\"KAR_MARJI\":\"0\",\"ODEME_NO\":\"21\",\"DOVIZ_BIRIMI\":\"USD\",\"NAKLIYE_TIP_NO\":\"11\",\"ROLE_ADI\":\"Bayi\"}";
```

Java code

```
public JSONObject stringToJson(String deneme2)
{
    JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.getString(deneme2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

and then error and exception. It doesn't change string value JSONObject

https://i.stack.imgur.com/roVu5.png

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what have you done? Do you know?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do??

Comment: What is `stringVeri`? And i think you should be using `json.putString()`

Comment: sorry stringVeri is deneme2

Comment: deneme2 is string value and deneme2 is JSON writing format. and then i sent deneme2 stringToJson function for string to JSON object bu return exceptation in image and null json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deneme2 is string value and deneme2 is JSON writing format. and then i sent deneme2 stringToJson function for string to JSON object bu return exceptation in image and null json.

Comment: thnks for advice i'm new user

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
```

is not taking the actual String which need to be converted.

```
public JSONObject stringToJson(String deneme2)
{
    JSONObject json= new JSONObject(deneme2); //pass a String here
    try {
        json.getString("key name");    //key for which you need to retrieve data
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnx for advice it's running :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you : Firstly convert above String to json object

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(deneme2);
try {
        String abc = json.getString("NUKE_USER_NO");    
       Log.i("Log", abc);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```